# Reading from StreamReader without consuming

Tags: python, sockets, python-asyncio, streamreader

I need to read from a `StreamReader` when a new connection is made in my `Server` instance created by using `asyncio.start_server` without consuming the internal buffer.

The first thing I tried to accomplish is to create a deep copy of the `StreamReader` object passed to the callback that handles the connection but it throws an error.

The second thing is to create a `StreamReader` from scratch by copying the buffer and the `transport` of the passed `StreamReader`

```
async def _handle_req(self, reader: StreamReader, writer: StreamWriter):

            reader_copy = StreamReader()
            reader_copy._buffer = deepcopy(reader._buffer)
            reader_copy.set_transport(reader._transport)
```

However when it comes to invoke `readline` from `reader_copy` it throws an `IncompleteReadError` exception. After doing some debugging I found that the exception is thrown by the internal `readuntil` function of `streams.py` `StreamReader` class (line 626) because for some reason the internal `self._eof` flag is set to `True`. This happens at line 515 in the `_wait_for_data` method

```
...
self._waiter = self._loop.create_future()
        try:
            await self._waiter
        finally:
            self._waiter = None
```

because the `await self._waiter` for some reason set it to `True`.

Is there an alternative solution or a way to create a copy of the `StreamReader`?

Comment: Probably not. Your best solution might be to read what you need, then create your own reader which re-reads that data you just read, and then reads from the socket

Comment: Maybe push the read data again in the `StreamReader`?